# Executing LLVM code results with Segmentation fault

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have the following code:

```
@.str_specifier = constant [4 x i8] c"%s\0A\00"
@.int_specifier = constant [4 x i8] c"%d\0A\00"
@.string_var1 = constant [2 x i8] c"f\00"
@.string_var2 = constant [6 x i8] c"Error\00"

;    >>> Start Program
declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)
declare void @exit(i32)
define void @print(i8*) {
    call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @.str_specifier, i32 0, i32 0), i8* %0)
    ret void
}
define void @printi(i32) {
    call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @.int_specifier, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %0)
    ret void
}
declare i8* @malloc(i32)
declare void @free(i8*)
declare void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i32(i8*, i8*, i32, i1)


define void @main()
{   ; >>> Adding function scope
    %funcArgs1 = alloca [50 x i32]

    ; >>> Adding function arguments allocation

    ; >>> Function body of main
    call void @print(i8* getelementptr ([2 x i8], [2 x i8]* @.string_var1, i32 0, i32 0))
    %register1 = call i8* @malloc(i32 48)
    %register2 = bitcast i8* %register1 to i32*
    %register3 = getelementptr inbounds [50 x i32], [50 x i32]* %funcArgs1, i32 0, i32 0
    %register4 = ptrtoint i32* %register2 to i32
    store i32 %register4, i32* %register3
    %register5 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register2, i32 0
    %register6 = add i32 0, 12
    store i32 %register6, i32* %register5
    %register7 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register2, i32 1
    %register8 = add i32 0, 2
    store i32 %register8, i32* %register7
    %register9 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register2, i32 2
    store i32 0, i32* %register9
    %register10 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register2, i32 3
    store i32 0, i32* %register10
    %register11 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register2, i32 4
    store i32 0, i32* %register11
    %register12 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register2, i32 5
    store i32 0, i32* %register12
    %register13 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register2, i32 6
    store i32 0, i32* %register13
    %register14 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register2, i32 7
    store i32 0, i32* %register14
    %register15 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register2, i32 8
    store i32 0, i32* %register15
    %register16 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register2, i32 9
    store i32 0, i32* %register16
    %register17 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register2, i32 10
    store i32 0, i32* %register17
    %register18 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register2, i32 11
    store i32 0, i32* %register18
    %register19 = load i32, i32* %register3 ; Get variable x
    %register20 = add i32 0, 2
    %register21 = inttoptr i32 %register20 to i32*
    %register22 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register21, i32 1
    %register23 = load i32, i32* %register22
    %register24 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %register21, i32 0
    %register25 = load i32, i32* %register24
    %register26 = add i32 %register23, %register25
    %register27 = sub i32 %register26, 4
    %register28 = icmp sgt i32 %register20, %register27
    br i1 %register28, label %label1, label %label_cont1
label_cont1:
    br label %label2
label1:
    call void @print(i8* getelementptr ([6 x i8], [6 x i8]* @.string_var2, i32 0, i32 0))
    call void @exit(i32 1)
    %register200 = add i32 0, 2
    br label %label2
label2:
    ret void

}   ; >>> Closing function scope
```

For some reason when I run it, it fails with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` without printing an understandable error. The strange thing is if I comment the commands in `label1` and keep it:

```
    ;call void @print(i8* getelementptr ([6 x i8], [6 x i8]* @.string_var2, i32 0, i32 0))
    ;call void @exit(i32 1)
    ;%register200 = add i32 0, 2
    br label %label2
```

It does not result with Segmentation fault. If I comment out at least one of those commands (for example print or the sum), it will fail. Why does it happen?

EDIT: I think I'm getting the [same result here](https://tio.run/##rVZRa9swEH73rxCFQBJMsOTEdVtWUsa218Ee21IcWzYC2wqyUlpKf3smyXEiXdy6M8uD5ch33/fpdCddWT5X@/160Ujx1GxpynJGBfqGUl43Mqklul@iF8TiR5ReTJqH4O4hCC689YLVctg@O9krfFYXT8@JwI41OVrnZ5bEsYyOlj@E4MJYezdI/W5vb9EfmQiJfgteiKTyMpqWiaCIhQSttwpP5lMWz320WCxmx6/PnGVoTV@YnCpDPZ@zups2Xtppht48zZImZWkAT0g2NiqopCWtaC23UqBpFwf/GJE5AmH2DVxwGGZqVDCTYGboBJVGiffeo4sZwf9TmLOf58LU2CvsEGbFsq6UDJ52kbQjnAtKTSTBfKlyb1HRKt2@LrYBi9uHAmgX0j5Coh545nluGKqE1dOZ96YE3ZgEuMsylTYo39WpZLxGTcq31Aie6Lk7UTQ684zIBN2vAr32kDx6xqYfIxHFTsetObjpSdv@Z2e44dkr4jnSqk57AhLpbCPIcSOIkyFdoYBtaMM/EbRgjaRtHZmtd6OPljGw1HW0YTJNGtmm2AlCcg0@d@1DZe9qZfWG7@qsseLmW@9zK8auaBd4qYAVnOQqIobX1thKMQ6N5IfiPbn6wCF0oVcfa25TyGXrlRfp/MiybgH4QzERxFu5QJdjxGAXI3bFfKglhnCXLs7VGC2QLYB2VyAXgzEs4RALBhuE8Ria5SANCD0mY2hWgzQE0IRjaKJBGlAZeDmG5nKQZgloRlVgPEgDSgtHY2iuBmkiQDOuhINBHlCdOB7Fgwd5YsCjj4GSJ1kfaqius1/6Vk8ESzYlRS/g/gj6zqLTZ12V6kSX3Mi3Dyfl2XvDkH@sMNx7RJLwk0URqHI5ihKcQGT1GSUoCWJfKJZq38YDLjrvmt0GuKgLB2LrxGFptUVNIWHQbYI24TZqtdj29lGZbGiJJmbA7t8n1XVL7Fnv1x2KbUZai8PHL7U80bHlifpaHtLb8ljIXbOOMOxxgt4k7VdMrt1O1ns/tnTfS96c95H7/V8). ([Here with comments](https://tio.run/##rVZRa9swEH73rxCFQBJMsOTEdVtWUsa218Ee21IcWzYC2wqyUlpKf3smyXEiXdy6M8uD5ch33/fpdCddWT5X@/160Ujx1GxpynJGBfqGUl43Mqklul@iF8TiR5ReTJqH4O4hCC689YLVctg@O9krfFYXT8@JwI41OVrnZ5bEsYyOlj@E4MJYezdI/W5vb9EfmQiJfgteiKTyMpqWiaCIhQSttwpP5lMWz320WCxmx6/PnGVoTV@YnCpDPZ@zups2Xtppht48zZImZWkAT0g2NiqopCWtaC23UqBpFwf/GJE5AmH2DVxwGGZqVDCTYGboBJVGiffeo4sZwf9TmLOf58LU2CvsEGbFsq6UDJ52kbQjnAtKTSTBfKlyb1HRKt2@LrYBi9uHAmgX0j5Coh545nluGKqE1dOZ96YE3ZgEuMsylTYo39WpZLxGTcq31Aie6Lk7UTQ684zIBN2vAr32kDx6xqYfIxHFTsetObjpSdv@Z2e44dkr4jnSqk57AhLpbCPIcSOIkyFdoYBtaMM/EbRgjaRtHZmtd6OPljGw1HW0YTJNGtmm2AlCcg0@d@1DZe9qZfWG7@qsseLmW@9zK8auaBd4qYAVnOQqIobX1thKMQ6N5IfiPbn6wCF0oVcfa25TyGXrlRfp/MiybgH4QzERxFu5QJdjxGAXI3bFfKglhnCXLs7VGC2QLYB2VyAXgzEs4RALBhuE8Ria5SANCD0mY2hWgzQE0IRjaKJBGlAZeDmG5nKQZgloRlVgPEgDSgtHY2iuBmkiQDOuhINBHlCdOB7Fgwd5YsCjj4GSJ1kfaqius1/6Vk8ESzYlRS/g/gj6zqLTZ12V6kSX3Mi3Dyfl2XvDkH@sMNx7RJLwk0URqHI5ihKcQGT1GSUoCWJfKJZq38YDLjrvmt0GuKgLB2LrxGFptUVNIWHQbYI24TZqtdj29lGZbGiJJmbA7t8n1XVL7Fnv1x2KbUZai8PHmy/1PNGx54n6eh7S2/PY0F27jjDscoLeNO3XTK7dXtZ7PzZ130venHeS@/1f))

I understand that "Segmentation fault" means that I tried to access memory that
I do not have access to. but why can't I even create an new register with some value?

EDIT2: It looks like `br i1 %register28, label %label1, label %label_cont1` is the real reason.

Edit3: The actual full code I'm trying to figure can be found [here](https://tio.run/##rVdtj9s2DP7uX0EUCJBcg9SSLL8kKHBF121ftgLtx/ZQOLGTE@DYme273q3Yb7@R8rujW@PD@sHRSeRDinxIsUlyf3x6ul6ptPxWnOKd2qs4h7ewy9KiDNMSvjjwAMq/gd2rWfTVfvfVtl9Z16uizH8uX3Tyf8d59owCF63GhzzPcojUvSpUlsL2EUivMynYQFPYI83sroRsD0VcQh6mh3gFH09reK0BoniXhHkMSnC4PuV44f1c@VdLWK1Wi/b0PlMRXMcPqpyjYLePknB9DJMk2w0PKoV9HseENt5PMLyrY3zcnR5XJ1v51QcBKtPVR3D8MFLdq7TR1B4qbQt@WDu0rD3vXO5fAg5xGSfxMU7LU5nDvEnCsk0Hej/MsbYLdv2zqH5n9sLKMXjkgvWPwSF9x//LnwGHzv1BmJE/lrXRvhxDlc7JjQ0AJfsLX62YfQMP9Hf1780beJ/HYanSA0kMJNkNPCKPHuA18M1YsuFQmGblLTKVtubfFV43icMIygzCKCLZ@n7Aae9xoS3USZvjd4F7m9aXz7fZXRJV54C4EB6zu1QbqnEK@H6rdregCmDWBu86CH514x/WbM/C/FCg95qKYU0eDJm0rVmuy0OnZkhXcPyFNSvoeKvKXViUVXhRAZ1HgStU5ng6zJtKt@hlVLRWUKVyoE4TagnUQtkyo5tVIkWDahVlVlccCjYIOUc15yJjBesMSbp0FDU0YUN02aI7KOtOQmeo4Q3Rh@BeC@6iqD8JvI9ktzg@4gSTcIQRJ6Ck25OAHCMQ0/Rhk5CkGYnCyfgkJNeMRERhYhKSZ0YShDSNc74ZiejF5CSkwIwkCWkiU20zFNGSedOgmBnKs7Y5JOE2TmCmf745ntUs1mTHf0mbYMFbSLIw6ssgFLUdu1d6eEbSnA86HGzg/e/v/vztwy/w66ePf6zRYllm2rSuTxb029hlhEEbXfVzosaZe5xYw@U0OO2@a4SjhPN@oyHDS/pS/jj1leJu25xg0yGucWoTanc8QXEomzNba/mUKsVoGSyHOduGERtt4dhUMqu3pmQKu0VPRuhOiy7sn6Mfsixq0OlYg583gXZkW3bLehQQbDgCVDPGaPYgb3D46h01oxrgADVmbt8pvdZeiekJFUZ@COKHoFwf76ppSGdTUNqE99xTTCoLkvDPXmNU6ngsgvOXlZTqpxUfOrsP0Ditz/2rfoj@cwjVZutpCyGXzWvt0kxKQcXdy54FdK6rKIebIuboIzEkuqabo2/k9IpD6G0KsSOn2ScgUjNWoUNV6HgN7eO/GtKRQkt5x6v5XTPJl8O/A241B@teH2UjM/40x3UMAqPX1Cllv1My7XEwHILsvsK4GlqfA051INmkHiv6PVZe9ryjjd78JkwXk3Rn6QynLxKmbTkuLUl5le7zpSUlzblaYlhauNVz35s86hJxpW@YdVvgYSb87oYeqQYvD7ZrqHMZTK1zCkFT5m5b5lI2ZT5mC7ObZx9XxBeXvSRmLjck3dUnYlJIXN4PyWWjHNroCsuVJv65zvnNcTIz7bWr9dnTpGr6udIQSJxy2tW699/Zp6d/AQ). The problem is that changing it to `alloca i32` will result with Error (instead of printing `1`). It also contains the C code I'm trying to copy to LLVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segfault originates from this line

```
%register21 = inttoptr i32 %register20 to i32*
```

After the cast, `register21` supposedly points to some memory location. But what memory location ?? It's value is a non existent address that wasn't gotten through a an `alloca` instr or `malloc` call.
Therefore all the other registers that try to dereference this pointer get disappointed.

[I've altered the inttptr line](https://tio.run/##rVbRatswFH33V4hCIAkmWHLiui0rKWPb62CPbSmOLRuBbQVZKS2l355JcpxIN27dmfXBTuWjc46u7pVuWT5X@/160Ujx1GxpynJGBfqGUl43Mqklul@iF8TiR5ReTJqH4O4hCC689YLVchifnfCKn9XF03MisIMmR3R@hiQOMjoifwjBhUF7N0j93d7eoj8yERL9FrwQSeVlNC0TQRELCVpvFZ/Mpyye@2ixWMyOX585y9CavjA5VUA9nrO6Gzaz9KQZevO0SpqUpSE8MdncqKCSlrSitdxKgaZdHPxjROYIhNk3dMHhNVNvRTMJZkZOUGmceO89vpgx/D@NOft5bky9e40dwqxU1pWywdMuknaEc0GpiSQYL1XuLSpapdvXxTZgcftQBO1C2kdI1APPPM8NQ5Wwejrz3pShG5MAd1mm0gbluzqVjNeoSfmWGsMTPXYnikZnnjGZoPtVoNcekkfPYPo5ElHsdNyawzQ9aON/dsANz14Rz5F2ddoTkEhnG0GOG0GcDOkKBWxDG/6JoAVrJG3ryGy9G320jAFS19GGyTRpZJtiJwrJNfncxYcK73pl9Ybv6qyx4uZbv@dWjF3TLvFSESs6yVVEjK7tsbViJjSSH4r3NNUHE0KXevWx5zaFXLVee5HOjyzrFoA/NBNBvpVLdDnGDHY5YtfMh15iSHfp8lyN8QLVAoi7ArkYjFEJh1Qw2CCMx8gsB2VA6DEZI7MalCFAJhwjEw3KgMrAyzEyl4MySyAzqgLjQRlQWjgaI3M1KBMBmXElHAzqgOrE8SgdPKgTAx19DJQ8yfpYQ3Wd/dK3eiJYsikpegH3R9B3Fp0@W/eqRtyo011ysxT7oFIsvbcN@cdqw73HJQk/WSCBjpejJMFpRFafSYLyIPblYrn2bT4wRedgs9uAKerygdw6iVhabVFTSBh0W6BNvo1aLbZn@6hMNrREE/PC7r9PqgOX2LN@X3csNoy0iMPHL7U/0bH9ifraH9Lb/ljMXeOOMOx3gt6E7XdMrt2u1ns/tnffS96c95T7/V8)

Comment: thanks for the answer! It does solve the segmented fault but why do I need `%register20` then? I actually have the full code (given by the professor) with that error but for some reason, changing it to `alloca` leads to other behavior. Do you mind look into it? I added the URL in the question. It should return `1` but instead it returns the Error.

Comment: I opened a separate topic so it will be more organized. If you might help, please take a look. thanks again :)